# Company's permanent establishment (OECD Tax treaty model article 5) and remote work

Tags: international, tax-law

**TL;DR** The info I'm looking for is if there is known cases when a digital nomad -style remote work has been triggered permanent establishment for a company?

**Background**
My employee has released a new remote work policy which limits foreign remote work quite a bit. The new policy is said to mitigate a risk of having permanent establishment in a foreign country.

Obviously this is a valid point for certain positions, such as senior executives. But how about others who has productive role. For example a consult or a coder who works in customer projects (something else than preparatory or auxiliary mentioned in paragraph 4 of Article 5).  Is there known cases when a digital nomad -style remote work has been triggered permanent establishment for a company? Studying former cases and circumstances leading to PE would help me understand the risk.

When I asked about cases the law company our company uses said that this is a post COVID-19 thing and that is the reason there is not such cases but risk is real. This is hard to understand though. Online work has been common practice in IT business for more than a decade and there was tax treaties in 20th century. So nothing new here.

I am located in Finland (you may understand why doing your work from somewhere warm and cozy feels tempting), but this is an international issue so cases from anywhere will do as long as tax treaty is based on OECD model. That is the case with every Finnish tax treaties.

There is heaps of other things you have to consider when doing remote work in foreign country, such as personal taxation, social security fees, visas, work permissions and so on. But in this question I focus on permanent establishment of a enterprise.

OECD tax treaty model and it's comments can be readed from here: https://read.oecd-ilibrary.org/taxation/model-tax-convention-on-income-and-on-capital-condensed-version-2017_mtc_cond-2017-en#page1

Comment: OECD is The Organization for Economic Cooperation and Development and they have quite widely accepted model for tax treaty. See https://read.oecd-ilibrary.org/taxation/model-tax-convention-on-income-and-on-capital-condensed-version-2017/commentary-on-article-5_mtc_cond-2017-8-en

Comment: And my question is hiding in the middle of the text: "Is there known cases when a digital nomad -style remote work has been triggered permanent establishment for a company? "

Comment: Actually UN has also model for tax treaty which is targeted between developing and developed countries. It's article 5 also defines PE and it is based on OECD's model.

Comment: Edit your question with the new info and clarify the question itself.

Comment: Clarified and added reference to the tax treaty model [x]